# How do I create a regex with regular variable and some fixed text in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pattern-matching, findall

In code i only want to fetch variable name from a c file which is used in if condition.
Following is code snippet of regex:

```
fieldMatch = re.findall(itemFieldList[i]+"=", codeline, re.IGNORECASE);
```

here i can find variable itemFieldList[i] from file.
But when i try to add `if` as shown below nothing is extracted as output even though variable exist in c code in if condition .

```
fieldMatch = re.findall(("^(\w+)if+[(](\w+)("+itemFieldList[i]+")="), codeline, re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE);
```

Can anyone suggest how can we create regex  to fetch mentioned scenario.

Sample Input :

```
IF(WORK.env_flow_ind=="R")
```

OR

```
IF( WORK.qa_flow_ind=="Q" OR WORK.env_flow_ind=="R")
```

here itemFieldList[i] = WORK.env_flow_ind

Comment: When nothing is extracted it means your pattern doesn't exist in file or regex is not properly written. You should add a sample input to your question.

Comment: Show your input data and describe what you want to match. `"^(\w+)if+[{](\w+)("+itemFieldList[i]+")=")` does not look sensible to me.

Comment: Added sample input in question.

Comment: That regex will not match that string. For example, what does `f+` mean? Where are the parts that match spaces? Round parentheses? Dots?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to make this a comment, which it should be and I can't say that I fully understand the question. But to point out a few things:

it's about adding variables to your regex then you should be using string templates to make it more understandable for us and your future self.

```
"^{}".format(variable)
```

Doing that will allow you to create a dynamic regex that searches for what you want.

Secondly, I don't think that is your problem. I think that your regex is malformed. I don't know what exactly you are trying to search for but I recommend reading the [python regex documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) and testing your regex on a resource like [regex101](http://www.regex101.com) to make sure that you're capturing what you intend to. From what I can see you are a bit confused about **groups**. When you put parenthesis around a pattern you are identifying it as a **group**. You were on the right track trying to exclude the parenthesis in your search by surrounding it with square brackets but it's simpler and cleaner to escape them.

if you are trying to capture this statement:

```
if(someCondition == fries)
```

and you want to extract the keyword fries the valid syntax for that pattern is:

```
(?=if\((?:[\w=\s])+(fries)\))
```

Since you want this to be dynamic you would replace the string *fries* with your string template, and you'll get code that ends up something like this:

```
p = re.compile("(?=if\((?:[\w=\s])+({})\))".format(search), re.IGNORECASE)
p.findall(string)
```

Regex101 does a better job of breaking down my regex than I ever will:

[Link cuz i have no rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxRZm.png)

Comment: Thanks ! Able to fetch string with regex : ifpattern = "\bif\b\s*\(.*?{0}=.*?\)".format(itemFieldList[i]);

Answer (score 1):

You can build the regex pattern as:

```
pattern = r"\bif\b\s*\(.*?\b" + re.escape(variablename) + r"\b"
```

This will look for the word “if” in lowercase, then optionally any spaces, then an opening parenthesis, then optionally any characters, and then your search term, its beginning and its end at word boundaries.

So if *variablename* is "WORK.env_flow_ind", then `re.findall(pattern, textfile)` will match the following lines:

```
if(blabla & WORK.env_flow_ind == "a")
if  (WORK.env_flow_id == "b")
if(WORK.env_flow_id == "b")
if( WORK.env_flow_id == "b")
```

and these won't match:

```
if (WORK.env_bla == "c")
if (WORK.env_flow_id2 == "d")
```

Comment: Thanks ! It helped .. Updated Regex : ifpattern = "\bif\b\s*\(.*?{0}=.*?\)".format(itemFieldList[i]);